# Is there any specific number of output arrows from decision node and input arrows to the merge node in activity diagram?

Tags: uml, ooad, activity-diagram, uml-decision-node, uml-merge-node

How many output arrows can be connected to the decision node and how many input arrows can be connected to the merge node in an activity diagram? Is there any possibility of having more than two output arrows to the decision node and input arrows to the merge node?

What is the maximum number of output arrows can be connected to decition node and input arrows to the merge node?I s there any possibility of using more than two?

Answer (score 3):

There is no limit, except for graphical reasons. You could always join the incoming arrows to a single one. Same for the outgoing wich you could split later.

See p. 390 of UML 2.5:

[image]